# Programmatically load the contents of a Product in a particular product type

Tags: commerce

I am developing an Ecommerce site and I am using [Drupal-commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module for it. I have an issue regarding loading the contents of a product which is: **How can I programmatically get the contents of all the products in a particular product type?**

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with an EntityFieldQuery:

```
<?php
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'product')
    ->execute();
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will help you.

```
$banner_query = db_select('node','n');
$banner_query->innerJoin('field_data_field_weight','w','w.entity_id = n.nid');  // join with another table
$banner_query->fields('n',array('nid')); 
$banner_query->fields('w',array('field_weight_value'));
$banner_query->condition('n.status',1,'=');  
$banner_query->condition('n.type','skin_and_hair_banners','=');
$banner_query->orderBy('w.field_weight_value','ASC');
$banner_res = $banner_query->execute();

while($banner_fetch = $banner_res->fetchObject()){
    $banner_load = node_load($banner_fetch->nid);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($banner_load)
}
```